# Всплывающая подсказка на SVG карте с помощью jquery.tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Добрый день,подскажите,пожалуйста,как сделать всплывающую подсказку на SVG  карте с помощью jquery.tooltip?
Например при наведении на надпись 'Воронежский фронт', вверху, в правой части карты

```
$( "#tspan4501" ).tooltip({
  content: "Awesome title!"
});
```

Если делать таким способом, не реагирует вообще.
Если вешаем на какой-нибудь другой блок,созданный нами - всё работает.

Карта:
https://jsfiddle.net/z5kcyukg/